# Magento 1.9: Newsletter subscribe checkbox not working

Tags: magento-1.9

I have installed magento 1.9 and have newsletter subscribe checkbox,
whenever i check it and submit success message shows but again checkbox is unchecked similarly for the unsubscribe case.

I there any solution to this problem.
Enabled the Mail chimp extension, which is working fine, but only checkbox is not working as expected.

Comment: Are you talking about the newsletter checkbox in the default _customer registration_ form and/or _My Account_ section or some other implementation?

Comment: @ChristophFarnleitner in the My Account section